# Autoit Unknown function name

Tags: function, autoit

I  get following error in my Script:

> ==> Unknown function name.:

Basically I have this:

```
   Local $sFoo_01 = "Z:\Foo\3\"
   Local $sFoo_02 = "Z:\Foo\6\"
   Local $sFoo_03 = "Z:\Foo\8\"
   Local $sFoo_04 = "Z:\Foo\9\"

Func Test()

      Local $aFooNew_01 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_01, "*")
      Local $aFooNew_02 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_02, "*")
      Local $aFooNew_03 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_03, "*")
      Local $aFooNew_04 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_04, "*")
      ...
EndFunc

...

      Local $aFooNew_01 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_01, "*")
      Local $aFooNew_02 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_02, "*")
      Local $aFooNew_03 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_03, "*")
      Local $aFooNew_04 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_04, "*")
```

Error:

```
  Local $aFooNew_01 = _FileListToArray($sFoo_01, "*")
                                       ^ Error
```

Answer (score 0):

the **_FileListToArray** function is included as a user defined function.so you must write `#include <File.au3>` in the header of your scripts to make it work.

Comment: You could also try this: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/111554-organize-includes-in-scite4autoit3/